# sql data to php calendar events

Tags: php, calendar

I find nice PHP calendar with events but I have problem to configure my data to format necessary for calendar events.

My data comes from MySql database

```
$select1ev = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM runbeh WHERE user=1 AND 
inttyzden=201806 ORDER BY id DESC");
while($data=mysqli_fetch_array($select1ev)) {
$id1=$data['id'];
$datid1=$data['datum'];
$datum1=date('Y-m-d', $datid1);
$km1=$data['vzdialenost'];
$link1="mypage&id=$id1";
}
```

Events data has to be at format:

```
$events = [
'2018-06-13' => ['text' => 8.02, 'href' => link/to/page],
'2018-06-11' => ['text' => 7.55, 'href' => link/to/page],
];
```

How I can transform my data $datum1 as 'date', $km1 as 'text' and $link1 as 'href'? Thanks a lot for help. I try more versions, but no one works. It is looks like my PHP knowledge is too low for this.

Comment: What is `datum`? `var_dump($data['datum'])` Maybe you need to be using an array here and the issue is that you are overwriting on every iteration?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$data = [
[
    'date' => '2018-06-13',
    'text' => 8.02,
    'href' => 'link/to/page1'
],
[
    'date' => '2018-06-11',
    'text' => 7.55,
    'href' => 'link/to/page2'
]
];

$events = [];

foreach($data as $datum) {
     $events[$datum['date']] = [
       'text' => $datum['text'],
       'href' => $datum['href']
     ];
}
```

Comment: I try your code but it gives me an error (not accepting ;). I need something like this:    $events = [ '$datum1' => ['text' => $km1, 'href' => $link1], '$datum1' => ['text' => $km1, 'href' => $link1],];

Comment: I just redid the answer, hopefully it helps. I tested it to make sure that there aren't any syntax errors. The $data = ..... is just to setup a way to test it. Instead of the foreach($data as $datum) { that would be your while($data=mysqli_fetch_array($select1ev)) {